# How to access a parameter of a function in another function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so i have been trying to create a dynamic firestore collection based on a paremeter of a function, but I want to access it in another function altho i do not know how.

Here is the first function that create the collection :

[image]

And here is the second function that I want to access `title` from :

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated ! Thank you!

CODE :

```
Future updateBooksData(String category, String title, String author,
      String numberOfPages, String description) async {
    return await subBookCollection.collection(title).doc(uid).set(
      {
        'category': category,
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'numberOfPages': numberOfPages,
        'description': description,
      },
    );
  }

  Future getBooksData() async {
    return subBookCollection.collection(title).get();
  }
```

Comment: Please do not paste the code as an image.

Comment: Why not pass the param in that as well? `Future getBooksData(String title)` ?

Answer (score 3):

pass the parameter to Future getBooksData(var title)